# Is it possible to sync data via Foundry Data Connection to a specific branch of a dataset?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-data-connection

I'd like to sync data ingested via Foundry Data Connection into a specific branch of a dataset. Is there a way to configure this kind of setup?

Answer (score 0):

You can sync data to a specific branch in the Data Connection UI:
[image]